# "Could not find function" in Roxygen examples during CMD check

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm running a CMD check on a package in RStudio, part of which analyses the `@examples` in the inline Roxygen documentation.

I'm getting this error:

```
checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘packagename-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: checkDate
> ### Title: Ensure that a date string is a valid date
> ### Aliases: checkDate
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> checkDate("2017-05-06")
Error: could not find function "checkDate"
```

Within my .R file, the documentation is defined as:

```
#' Ensure that a date string is a valid date
#'
#' @param dateString A string (eg. "2017-12-04").
#' @return TRUE or FALSE (and a warning if FALSE).
#' @examples
#' checkDate("2017-05-06")
#' checkDate("2017-05-40")
```

I am using devtools 1.13.2 and roxygen2 6.0.1, both of which I believe to be up-to-date at time of posting.

I have other packages using this same devtools/roxygen2 combination but have never before seen it fail to find a function name in `@examples` within its scope.

Someone else seems to have experienced something similar as an update to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416902/examples-error-could-not-find-function-building-packages-in-r), but I can't see that anyone says how to fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that you need to `#' @export` the function in the Roxygen comment, otherwise the function is not exported to the namespace of the package and it cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any way to include examples in the documentation without making the function public? (for other developers of the package)

Comment: EDIT:  I guess this isn't necessary - can just include comments.

Comment: @Serenthia You could try `pkg:::function`, then you don't have to make the function public.

Comment: With the `pkg:::function` approach you'll likely receive [a warning, and it may stop the package being accepted on CRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36852140/5977215)

Comment: Yes, that is true, could do some trick like `do.call(":::", list(pkgname, functionname)` to overcome this, but it is not recommended anyway...