# "could not find function" when running examples in package check

Tags: r, dplyr

When running `R CMD check` I am getting

```
> checking examples ... ERROR
...
...
  > lfqplotter$pca()
  Error in inner_join(wide$annotation, xx) : 
    could not find function "inner_join"
  Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
  Execution halted
```

A similar question was asked before.
["Could not find function" in Roxygen examples during CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722297/could-not-find-function-in-roxygen-examples-during-cmd-check)

But in my case it is a function from an imported package (dplyr), which I did list under Imports in the DESCRIPTION file.

```
Imports:
dplyr
```

I know that I could specify and `@importFrom` clause with `roxygen2`. However because the package contains dozens of functions with examples, and many use `dplyr::inner_join` and other `dplyr` functions, I would prefer not have to fill the comments with hundreds of `@importFrom dplyr inner_join select etc etc`, or be adding `@import dplyr` everywhere. Alternatively, I could, but I do not want to prefix every dplyr function call with `dplyr::`. Is there any other option to get examples working and imported package functions visible?

### Answer

Based on the Answer by @Roland and @Waldi I added an R file `AAA_importFrom.R` to the project with a block of:

```
#' @importFrom tidyr ...
#' @importFrom dplyr ...
...
#'
NULL
```

and removed all the @importFrom clauses from the function documentations.

Comment: It's not sufficient to have a package under `Imports` in the DESCRIPTION file (study *Writing R Extensions*). You must additional import specific (or all) functions in your NAMESPACE file. An alternative option would be to list the package under `Depends` in your DESCRIPTION file. But that's not recommended practice (in particular for `dplyr`which is not shy with masking base functions).

Comment: @Roland Since I am using roxygen2 I am not editing NAMESPACE by hand. What other option of adding the imports to the namespace do I have?

Comment: Well, the options are `@import` or `@importFrom` directives in roxygen2. Unfortunately, you say you are unhappy with these. So, you don't want roxygen2 to manage your NAMESPACE file but you also don't want to manage it manually. I'm not sure what kind of advice you are looking for if you already exclude all sensible options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also have :

```
importFrom(dplyr,inner_join)
```

in NAMESPACE

you can get Roxygen to create this in NAMESPACE by having :

```
#' @ImportFrom dplyr inner_join
NULL
```

in one of your package's R scripts